# simple scala help:llegal start of simple expression

Tags: scala, function, variables

I am learning scala and I think I don't understand something pretty basic. I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this online. I want to declare a variable within a function so that I can do some manipulations, as I will do in something like Python or Java. So, for example I declare this code outside of a function and it has no issues:

```
  var myint = 10;
```

However, when I try to do any declaration, so for example declare the same variable inside a function:

```
  def product [A,B](xs:List[A]) (ys:List[B]) =
    var myint = 10;
```

I am getting "illegal start of simple expression". Why is this happening? What is the difference between declaring inside and outside of functions?

What I want to do overall is declare a new variable that takes these two lists and creates a list of lists. So if xs = [1,2] and ys = [6,7], I want to create a variable that is [[1,2][6.7]]. How could I create this variable inside the product function?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Braces, `def f = { stuff }`. To contain more than an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a variable.  Just return the new list of lists. (You also don't need semicolons.)

```
def product[A](xs: List[A], ys: List[A]): List[List[A]] = 
  List(xs,ys)
```

Scala is a statically typed language.  It keeps a close eye on the type of all elements, arguments, return types, etc.  Notice how the return type changes if the two lists are of different types.

```
def product[A,B](xs: List[A], ys: List[B]): List[List[Any]] =
  List(xs,ys)
```

This amounts to a loss of type information, which usually leads to bad outcomes.  Avoid it.